# Vuetify Datepicker- Enabled multiple property but showing wrong selected Dates count

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

I have  to show date field. After giving multiple true, the picker is showing wrong value.

Added code:

```
<v-date-picker :landscape="$store.state[parentName].landscape" v-model="$store.state[parentName].picker" 
                       :multiple= "true"
                       @input="handleInput" >
        </v-date-picker>
```

[image]

Please help me out. From where this **10 selected** is coming. Where did i went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think from your code, your v-model data, `$store.state[parentName].picker` already have any value.

You can see this value using Vue.js devtools.
If don't have any value on v-model, please anotate the comment.

If you already have any value, and you don't expect
You should clear the `$store.state[parentName].picker` in `beforeMount` or `beforeCreate`.

Comment: I am passing a string date value. Is that the cause of issue?

Comment: Like @nabeen  has mentioned, your $store.state[parentName].picker would have 10 dates and passing string date in YYYY-MM-DD format is fine and not the cause of the issue.

Comment: "10 selected" means v-model have 10 data. Maybe `$store.state[parentName].picker` have 10 data like `['2020-07-04', '2020-07-05', ...]`. So displayed "10 selected". `$store` is global, so other function affect. Try v-model use `data` of this component ?